# Java synchronization using .wait(millis)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, wait

I have a "little problem" about synchronization, this is my Scenario (I still don't know enough about synchronization, I'm still learning):
(EDIT)

```
        Thread work, progress;
        final Object myObject;
        work = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                myObject.doSomething();
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        });

        progress = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(myObject.progress());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        work.setDaemon(true);
        progress.setDaemon(true);

        work.start();
        progress.start();

        work.join();
        progress.interrupt();
        progress.join();

        /*Other code*/
```

(EDIT: maybe solved)

The main job is done in the WORK thread, and the progress of the job is printed in the PROGRESS thread;

This works good, but I'd like a better... "synchronization":
The only 'little' problem is that, if I put like 1 hour in the sleep method, maybe the job is already done and must wait those 55 minutes for the PROGRESS thread to terminate...
How to deal with this situation? I want my PROGRESS thread to terminate as the job is done, and not waiting for the sleep method to complete.
I suppose I'll have to use some synchronized blocks, as well as a .wait(millis) call instead of that .sleep(millis)...
Can someone help me undestand? Thanks!

Comment: If the goal is to have a progress system being updated, you might consider passing the progress updater to the worker object (via an interface), and then have the worker call update on the progress monitor. It is how, e.g., Eclipse implements progress updating.

Comment: Look at wait/notify/notifyAll, or the more advanced features in `java.util.concurrent` (and sub-packages).

Comment: You could also simply interrupt the progress thread when the work thread is done (i.e. after join() returns). No need for the thread-unsafe `done` array. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried using a wait/notify system with a .wait(millis) so that the PROGRESS thread immediately terminates, but it didn't work: The program simply enters the first synchronized block it encounters, and nothing else (if WORK thread synchronization block is reached first, then I get no print from the PROGRESS one, viceversa I only get the print of the progress, but no work)...

Comment: @JBNizet I know, I'm using that boolean array for a future implementation of a wait/notify system, using the value to prevent a spurious wake-up.

Comment: You simply want to stop the progress thread. I wouldn't need wait notify to do that. I would just interrupt it. Interrupting it will make it go out of the sleeping state immediately.

Comment: @JBNizet I think I got what you're trying to say: I modified my post, this is working now.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure but I think that last .join() is redundant, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you may want to look into the Observer/Listener pattern. To put it simply, your Observer will do nothing until it gets notified by the class it's subscribed to.

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077258/learn-java/observer-and-observable.html

```
// Your observable class
import java.util.Observable;
public class ObservableValue extends Observable
{
    private int n = 0;
    public ObservableValue(int n)
    {
        this.n = n;
    }
    public void setValue(int n)
    {
        this.n = n;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
    public int getValue()
    {
        return n;
    }
}


// Your observer
import java.util.Observer;
import java.util.Observable;
public class TextObserver implements Observer {
    private ObservableValue ov = null;
    public TextObserver(ObservableValue ov) {
        this.ov = ov;
    }
    public void update(Observable obs, Object obj) {
        if (obs == ov) {
            System.out.println(ov.getValue());
        }
    }
}


public class Main {
    public Main() {
        ObservableValue ov = new ObservableValue(0);
        TextObserver to = new TextObserver(ov);
        ov.addObserver(to);
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
    }
}
```

An example of using the observer pattern with multithreading can be found here:
https://dzone.com/articles/the-observer-pattern-using-modern-java

An interesting approach to this problem is using Reactive principles. A quick demonstration and explanation can be seen in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=weWSYIUdX6c

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I solved the main problem, but I'll take a peek at those links anyway!